# Diffing a PHP class file

Tags: windows, php, diff

I'm looking for a program that can diff/merge code files, and be aware of method names.

Currently, I'm diffing two files in WinMerge - one is a class called Core_Search, the other is a class called Search (this extends Core_Search so it can inherit all the methods, then override one or two). Core_Search contains (say) 20 methods, and Search contains one of those, with the same method name, but slightly different contents.

WinMerge's diff overview looks like this: http://img864.imageshack.us/img864/1657/diff.png because it's comparing one method to the entire class, not looking to find a matching method name.

Do any diffing/merging programs offer this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [SourceGear DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/index.html).
I haven't tested it with php, but it is a really nice tool!